# How to edit a bootstrap CSS file or use it?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend, bootstrap-5

Brand new to web development and running through a course and decided to make life difficult for myself by trying to edit a template for a forum website from the deep dark places of the internet.

It uses a boostrap link for the css file, this is currently outside of my skillset. Was hoping for a point in the right direction.

Either; how to use/read the bootstrap file, how to download it to a conventional css file for visual studio and or a point in the right direction of an as good source code I can use as a base to build my own.

Thanking you for your time.

Daniel

Googled what bootstrapping is; how to edit a bootstrap css file, how to read a bootstrap file and put my head gently on the keyboard and had an exertential crisis, searched stackoverflow for the meaning of life.

No good on any front.

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:bootstrap-4] *and* [tag:bootstrap-5]. It's highly unlikely that the template you are using is using *both* of those.

Comment: The documentation for Bootstrap 4 and 5 both have documentation on this in a fairly obvious top level menu item.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below 2 tags to link with bootstrap 5:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Try following the tutorial in the link below for more details:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap5/